# Regular expression to find character patterns in free text

Tags: regex

I have an application that parses files and converts them to XML. One of the processing modules in the application uses regular expressions to find patterns in free text. I am trying to identify 2 patterns but am not being very successful.

Pattern 1: 2 letters (excluding vowels) followed by 2 digits (1-9) followed by 2 letters (excluding vowels) and then 2 more letters which are defined (e.g.: WP, NL, GP, EC, etc.). There may or may not be spaces between each of groups.

Examples:

```
BQ 12 RT WP
BQ12RTGP
BQ12RT GP
```

Pattern 2: 3 letters (a-z) followed by 3 digits (1-9) followed by 2 more letters which are defined (e.g.: WP, NL, GP, EC, etc.). There may or may not be spaces between each of groups.

Examples:

```
ABC 123 GP
ABC123GP
ABC123 GP
```

This is an example of a regex that finds specifics words in text:

Comment: Your example is missing? What have you tried?

Comment: Are the letters always in uppercase?

Comment: Which language are you using? Not all regular expression syntax is the same

Comment: Jodes, for this simple task they are all alike.

Answer (score 4):

Since you aparrently don't have much experience with regular expressions, I'm going to explain a lot here.

First a little background: Regular expressions have tokens and quantifiers. Tokens are things that match something, e.g. `A` is a token that matches a Latin capital letter A. Quantifiers apply to tokens by being placed after them and modify how often that token can match in a row, e.g. `+` is a quantifier so that preceding token matches at least once, so `A+` matches `A`, `AAAA`, or `AAAAAAAAA`.

With that out of the way, a little primer on different kinds of tokens you're going to need.

1. One we already mentioned: Literal characters, such as `A`, `1` or others. You'll need this for the parts that can take one of a few defined values. `WP` will match `WP` but nothing else.
2. There are character classes. Those are written in square brackets and encompass various characters, each of which could match. The character class `[AB]` will match *either* `A` *or* `B`. There can also be character ranges, so `[A-Z]` will match any uppercase Latin letter that is part of ASCII, `[1-9]` will match any digit from `1` through `9`.

Then a few quantifiers we're going to need:

1. `?` causes the preceding token to match either not at all or exactly once, so `AB?` (remember, the `?` applies only to the `B` – the directly preceding token) will match either `A` or `AB`. If possible it will always try to match `AB`.
2. Exact repetitions can be written with `{5}` – that is, a number in curly braces. `A{2}` will match `AA`.

Ok, we can now start constructing the regex.

First of all we need a character class that encompasses letters without vowels. `[A-Z]` obviously will include them, so that doesn't suffice. But we can use multiple ranges:

```
[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]
```

Not pretty, but works. Some regex engines have provisions for actual set operations, e.g. set difference to use a character class and exclude certain characters again, but this will suffice for now.

We need two of those, though, since there are two letters:

```
[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{2}
```

Then there is a space or maybe not. There is a shorthand character class that includes all whitespace (including spaces and tabs): `\s`. We can use that, unless there is a strict requirement that only spaces may appear: `\s?`. For added robustness we can also use `\s*` which will match any number of spaces, even none if there aren't any.

Then we need digits from `1` through `9`: `[1-9]` and two of them again actually: `[1-9]{2}`. So far we have the following:

```
[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{2}\s*[1-9]{2}
```

Then we need two letters without vowels, again with a space or not:

```
[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{2}\s*[1-9]{2}\s*[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{2}\s*
```

After that there is a part where one of several defined options is possible. Those can be written with an alternation which uses the vertical bar `|`. We first need a group which is written with parentheses, just like in math, to restrict the precedence of the alternation (again, just like in math). Inside them we just list all possible options separated by `|`:

```
(WP|NL|GP|EC|etc.)
```

This is just like character classes, only that this will match more than one character (but still only one option from those presented).

Putting it all together we have

```
[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{2}\s*[1-9]{2}\s*[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{2}\s*(WP|NL|GP|EC|etc.)
```

Then there is one little thing. This will match even if there are characters surrounding it, since regular expressions in most engines will match substrings by default. We never said anywhere that what we match above needs to be a single “word” so to speak, it could be that we find `khdgdfgergBQ12RTGPrteryefg` somewhere. To prevent that there are certain assertions that will themselves not match any characters, but tie the match to specific places. One of them that is handy is `\b` which will match anywhere where there is a boundary between a character from `\w` (a shorthand character class that is utterly useless in practice and includes letters, digits and the underscore) and a character not from `\w`. For quick and dirty hacks `\b` is good enough to ensure that we match the beginning or end of a word, e.g. `\bfoo\b` will match `foo` in `a foo b` but not in `foobar`. There are options that are more robust, but also longer to write. So we can use the following which should be good enough for some purposes:

```
\b[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{2}\s*[1-9]{2}\s*[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]{2}\s*(WP|NL|GP|EC|etc.)\b
```

I'll leave the construction of the second pattern to you now, though. You should now know enough to do it yourself.

A really good site to learn regular expressions is [regular-expressions.info](http://regularexpressions.info) by the way. Things are explained *way* better than I could ever do and it's equally useful for learning and as a reference.

Comment: +1, that is really an impressive answer, that one can learn from (and not only give him the codez).

Comment: An amazing response... really appreciated. I have tested it against a test dataset and the hit rate was 99.76% (the 12 misses where not because on the expression but badly written text and punctuation that should not have been there). Thanks. tc./

Comment: Good to hear I could be of some help :-)

Comment: Really good post thanks so much, one of the explanations i've seen for regex defiantly bookmarking this page. I had a fairly different case but you led me to the correct answer anyway. top work :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

**Pattern1:**

```
[^\W\d_.AEIOUYaeiouy]{2}\s*\d{2}\s*[^\W\d_.AEIOUYaeiouy]{2}\s*(?:WP|NL|GP|EC)
```

Pretty straightforward, using an invert group because it's shorter than `[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxzBCDFGHJKLMPQRSTVWXZ]`, if you can make it case insensitive or know it will always be upper case you can make it shorter. adding more 2 letter "words" can be done by adding `|XX`to the last portion (inside the parenthesis).

**Pattern2:**

```
[A-Za-z]{3}\s*\d{3}\s*(?:WP|NL|GP|EC)
```

Depending on what language you are using you might need to change some things.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the letters must be in uppercase:

Pattern 1: `[BCDFGHJ-NP-TV-Z]{2}\s*[1-9]{2}\s*[BCDFGHJ-NP-TV-Z]{2}\s*(?:WP|NL|GP|EC)`

Pattern 2: `[A-Z]{3}\s*[1-9]{3}\s*(?:WP|NL|GP|EC)`

You may also want to consider adding `\b` to the start and end of each if you require that the strings be bordered by a non-word character or the start/end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this regex

```
^(?!.*[aeiou].*(WP|NL|GP|EC))[a-zA-Z]{2}\s*\d{2}\s*[a-zA-Z]{2}\s*(WP|NL|GP|EC)$
```